# Can a UITableViewCell know that it should be in grouped mode?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

Is there a way for a cell, if used in a grouped table view, detect that fact and modify its appearance as ro not overlap the rounded rect borders?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to do this. If you are making a custom cell you can just add a boolean property to the cell and set it when you create the cell. Or, you can do this:

```
UITableView *parentTable = (UITableView *)self.superview;
if (parentTable.style == UITableViewstyleGrouped {
//Do what you need to do for a grouped cell
}
else {
//Do what you need to do for a plain cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In a grouped table view, such a cell will always be the 1st or last of the section. You can easily identify it in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, by looking at the `indexPath` parameter.

Comment: The same can be said for a cell in a grouped table with only one section.

Comment: I never said there should be more than one section. I said the cell will be the 1st cell or the last cell of each section.